# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. for Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe called `output`. The basic issue is that I would like to set a certain row, column in the `dataframe` to a list using the `ix` function and am getting `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.` My understanding is that a dataframe element was like a list element, it could hold anything (string, list, tuple, etc). Am I not correct?

Basic setup:

```
import pandas as pd
output = pd.DataFrame(data = [[800.0]], columns=['Sold Count'], index=['Project1'])
print output.ix['Project1', 'Sold Count']
# -> 800
```

works fine:

```
output.ix['Project1', 'Sold Count'] = 400.0
print output.ix['Project1', 'Sold Count']
# -> 400.0
```

doesn't work:

```
output.ix['Project1', 'Sold Count'] = [400.0]
# -> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: Why do you want to set a list?

Comment: @AnandSKumar. This is a simple example, by sometimes there will be multiple values so a list makes sense i.e.`[400.0, 200.0]`

Answer (score 26):

If you really want to set a list as the value for the element, the issue is with the `dtype` of the column, when you create the DataFrame, the dtype gets inferred as `float64` , since it only contains numeric values.

Then when you try to set a list as the value, it errors out, due to the `dtype` . A way to fix this would be to use a non-numeric dtype (like `object`) or so. Example -

```
output['Sold Count'] = output['Sold Count'].astype(object)
output.loc['Project1','Sold Count'] = [1000.0,800.0] #Your list
```

Demo -

```
In [91]: output = pd.DataFrame(data = [[800.0]], columns=['Sold Count'], index=['Project1'])

In [92]: output
Out[92]:
          Sold Count
Project1         800

In [93]: output['Sold Count'] = output['Sold Count'].astype(object)

In [94]: output.loc['Project1','Sold Count'] = [1000.0,800.0]

In [95]: output
Out[95]:
               Sold Count
Project1  [1000.0, 800.0]
```

---

You can also specify the `dtype` while creating the DataFrame, Example -

```
output = pd.DataFrame(data = [[800.0]], columns=['Sold Count'], index=['Project1'],dtype=object)
output.loc['Project1','Sold Count'] = [1000.0,800.0]
```

Demo -

```
In [96]: output = pd.DataFrame(data = [[800.0]], columns=['Sold Count'], index=['Project1'],dtype=object)

In [97]: output.loc['Project1','Sold Count'] = [1000.0,800.0]

In [98]: output
Out[98]:
               Sold Count
Project1  [1000.0, 800.0]
```