# Error when trying to create n-grams from a column DataFrame

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

Given a `DataFrame` that has a single column `Text`:

```
      Text
0     chest  pain  nstemi  this  84-year  old  man  present  on  26/5  with  
      chest  pain  associate  with  profuse  sweating  and  nausea
```

I would like to create two new columns with unigrams and bigrams generated for the previous `DataFrame`.

This is the method I am using for generating the ngrams:

```
    def generate_ngrams(self, s, n):
        # Convert to lowercases
        s = s.lower()

        # Replace all none alphanumeric characters with spaces
        s = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]', ' ', s)

        # Break sentence in the token, remove empty tokens
        tokens = [token for token in s.split(" ") if token != ""]

        # Use the zip function to help us generate n-grams
        # Concatentate the tokens into ngrams and return
        ngrams = zip(*[tokens[i:] for i in range(n)])
        return [" ".join(ngram) for ngram in ngrams]
```

And that's how I am trying to populate my `DataFrame`:

```
    for index, row in featuresDF.iterrows():
        featuresDF.at[index, '1-gram'] = generate_ngrams(infoDF.at[index, 'Text'], 1)
        featuresDF.at[index, '2-gram'] = generate_ngrams(infoDF.at[index, 'Text'], 2)
```

When I run it, I get the following error : `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

Here's the Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-64-e014e2e1c7e2>", line 3, in <module>
    featuresDF.at[index, '1-gram'] = featureExtraction.generate_ngrams(infoDF.at[index, 'Text'], 1)

  File "C:\Users\as\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 2287, in __setitem__
    self.obj._set_value(*key, takeable=self._takeable)

  File "C:\Users\as\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2815, in _set_value
    engine.set_value(series._values, index, value)

  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 95, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.set_value

  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 106, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.set_value
```

I understand that it is an issue when I am assigning the unigrams and bigrams to the `DataFrame`, right? But I am not sure how to solve it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

generate_ngrams() should return a string, but it returns a list like:

```
['chest', 'pain', .....]
```

Before returning list you cant convert it to comma separated string like:

```
chest,pain, .....
```

by adding these lines:

```
ngramList = [" ".join(ngram) for ngram in ngrams]        
return ','.join(ngramList)
```

Additionally you can use CountVectorizer for finding N-grams:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(2,2)) # 2,2 means 2-gram, 1,1 is unigram
corpus = ['the boy is gone !']
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
print(vectorizer.get_feature_names()) # this will print the list containing gram values
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a list by using `return [" ".join(ngram) for ngram in ngrams]`

Instead of returning the list, only return the string itself:

`return " ".join(ngram) for ngram in ngrams`

If you yet really wish to set the element with a list, follow this [ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. for Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33221655/valueerror-setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence-for-pandas)